# Set Different Terminal Background for Each Directory

Tags: bash, zsh

I seem to recall stumbling across an article on zsh about how it was possible to have different themes (or presumably, different theme settings, for different directories). In other words, you'd be able to do things like set the background color of the terminal to be blue for one directory, black for another, etc. I couldn't find the original article or anything matching what I had in mind.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Why is bash tagged? Do you want bash or zsh answers (or either)?

Comment: Whichever works, though preferably zsh.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `LS_COLORS`, you can select highlighting, emboldening and different colours very quickly and easily.
heres a great tutorial on how to do that;
 https://www.howtogeek.com/307899/how-to-change-the-colors-of-directories-and-files-in-the-ls-command/

It is also possible to edit the `bash_profiles.` script line;
    `export BASH_IT_THEME="whichever theme you have"`
And insert a downloaded theme but this would be for your whole system (as far as I know)